# Use try-with-resource to read a text file line by line in java

Tags: java, io

For example, here is one way to read a text file line by line:

```
ArrayList<String> fidiidList = new ArrayList<String>();
String sampleLine;

String fileStem = "/tmp/x.txt";
File sampleFile = new File(fileStem);
BufferedReader sampleBuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sampleFile));
while ((sampleLine = sampleBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
    fidiidList.add(sampleLine);
}
sampleBuffer.close();
```

You have to close the buffer manually. I am wondering if it's ok to do it this way:

```
try(BufferedReader sampleBuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sampleFile))) {
    while ((sampleLine = sampleBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
        fidiidList.add(sampleLine);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which according to my textbook promises to close objects automatically.

BTW, when I type this in my IDE, it reminds me to bring language level from 1.8 to 1.7, does this mean Java 8 stopped supporting this feature?

Comment: No, Java 8 also supports try-with-resource.

Comment: could you elaborate in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Java 7. Use Java 7's file API:

```
final List<String> allLines 
    = Files.readAllLines(pathToYourFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Since Java 8 you can even obtain a `Stream` of all lines in a file using [`Files.lines()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-).

---

As to your IDE telling you to bring language level to 1.7, it is probably because you don't use Java 8 features.

---

Other side note: I highly doubt that you will be able to read text lines from a PDF, as your code seems to attempt doing...

Comment: oh, not my intention, just a careless example. thank s for pointing out, it's now corrected.

Comment: Does the using of Stream do away the necessity of closing the file?

Comment: According to the javadoc, you can do without it, yes; however, since `Stream` implements `AutoCloseable`, you can create it in a try-with-resources for better control.